# Linux tar command: compressing a directory but exluding subdirectories

Tags: php, command-line, tar

**Scenario:** I have a directory on a server that hosts my website that contains hundreds of user-submitted images. I am creating a backup script that takes all the images from the directory and compresses them into one .tar.gz file. The command I have so far is:
tar -czpf /path/to/backups/my_backup.tar.gz path/to/images/
**Problem:** No inside my path/to/images/ I have a directory called tmp/. When I run the command, I get a .tar.gz file containing all the image in the path/to/images/ directory and a subdirectory called tmp/. 
**Question:** How can I get the command to skip/not include the tmp/ subdirectory in the .tar.gz file.

Thanks a million in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for the `--exclude` argument.

```
--exclude=PATTERN
```

Some users find `exclude` options confusing.  Here are some common pitfalls:

- The main operating mode of `tar` does not act on a path name
  explicitly listed on the command line if one of its file name
  components is excluded.  In the example above, if you create an
  archive and exclude files that end with `*.o`, but explicitly name
  the file `dir.o/foo` after all the options have been listed,
  `dir.o/foo` will be excluded from the archive.
- You can sometimes confuse the meanings of `--exclude=PATTERN` and
  `--exclude-from=FILE-OF-PATTERNS` (`-X FILE-OF-PATTERNS`).  Be
  careful: use `--exclude=PATTERN` when files to be excluded are
  given as a pattern on the command line.  Use
  `--exclude-from=FILE-OF-PATTERNS` to introduce the name of a file
  which contains a list of patterns, one per line; each of these
  patterns can exclude zero, one, or many files.
- When you use `--exclude=PATTERN`, be sure to quote the PATTERN
  parameter, so GNU `tar` sees wildcard characters like `*`.  If you
  do not do this, the shell might expand the `*` itself using files
  at hand, so `tar` might receive a list of files instead of one
  pattern, or none at all, making the command somewhat illegal.
  This might not correspond to what you want.

For example, write:

```
$ tar -c -f ARCHIVE.TAR --exclude '*.o' DIRECTORY
```

rather than:

```
$ tar -c -f ARCHIVE.TAR --exclude *.o DIRECTORY
```

- You must use use shell syntax, or globbing, rather than `regexp`
  syntax, when using exclude options in `tar`.  If you try to use
  `regexp` syntax to describe files to be excluded, your command
  might fail.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are very right that --exclude can be a bit confusing. I did not understand it 100% myself until i read your explanations. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
tar -czpf /path/to/backups/my_backup.tar.gz --exclude path/to/images/tmp path/to/images/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (assuming GNU tar):

```
tar -czpf /path/to/backups/my_backup.tar.gz --exclude=tmp path/to/images/
```